# Controlling <input> box sizes in a Bootstrap inline form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap v3 inline form:

```
<div id="searchsection" hidden>
  <form id="searchform" class="form-inline" role="form">
    <label>Find:</label> 
    <select id="field" class="form-control">
      <optgroup label="Strings">
        <option value="authors" selected="selected">Authors</option>
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="pub">Publication Name</option>
        <option value="keywords">Keywords</option>
        <option value="physloc">Physical Location</option>
        <option value="comment">Comment</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Dates">
        <option value="datepub">Publication Date</option>
        <option value="dateread">Date Read</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>  

    <input type="text" id="narrowon1" class="form-control"/>
    <label for="narrowon2" class="form-control"></label> 
    <input type="text" id="narrowon2" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYYMM" hidden/>
    <input type="button" id="narrower" name="narrower" value="Narrow" class="form-control btn btn-primary"/>
    <input type="button" id="widener" name="widener" value="Widen" class="form-control btn btn-primary"/>
  </form>
</div> <!-- end of searchsection -->
```

I would like to reduce the width of the boxes narrowon1 and narrowon2 when the optgroup is Dates so that they would only hold six digits each; I am thinking of setting size="6". However, when I simply add those attributes in jQuery via a statement such as

```
$('#narrowon1').attr('size',"6");
```

they don't affect the rendered output. I expect the Bootstrap classes are overriding my additions.

What is a "Bootstrap-friendly" way to alter the sizes of these input boxes?

Comment: I can't really do much without seeing your `CSS`

Comment: My only CSS is the inclusion of bootstrap and jQuery-UI with `    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />`. I imagine I can do almost all the styling I want to do by adding some Bootstrap classes, and figuring out which ones I need is part of my problem I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maxlength` attribute will not be affected by any `CSS` applied to the `<input>`. How are you applying it in `javascript` as you can't limit the character length with CSS?

I think you might be mistaking the `maxlength` attribute with the actual `width` of the `<input>`. Here is a some info on the attribute: [Maxlength Attribute](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html)

View the log and make sure your `<input>` looks like this:

```
<input maxlength="6" name="someInput" />
```

**Edit:**

Place a class of your own on the input and place new styles on the `<input>`. Make sure your local `CSS` file loads after the bootstrap `CSS`. Than you can easily override it.

If you can't create a new `CSS` file, try `$('input').css('width', '200px');` with `jQuery`

Comment: In my javascript I have the jquery statement, ` $('#narrowon1').attr('maxlength',"6");
` for example.

Comment: Actually that maxlength change does take effect. But the change to resize the input box with `$('#narrowon1').attr('size',"6");` is ineffective. I expect this is because some Bootstrap class also tries to control the box's size.

Comment: Thanks, your jQuery `.css` does work. I feel slightly dirty specifying a number of pixels because I want it to look right on all screens. That was why I wanted to specify size=6, because I want to limit the user's input to six characters, irrespective of display resolution

Comment: you can do that, just include `maxlength="6"` AND the `CSS` change

Comment: (I know setting maxlength limits how many chars the user can enter. But I also wanted to size the textbox appropriately for this small input.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to wrap each input field inside a div with the class of col-sm-2
you can change the number with which ever you like.

Comment: I tried wrapping one of my <input> boxes (fifth line from bottom in my code snippet above) like this:  `<div class="col-sm-2">
   <input type="text" id="narrowon2" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYYMM" hidden/>
 </div>` but this forced the rendering to break into two lines, i.e. it interfered with `class="form-inline"` somehow.

Comment: this functionality seems to be b

Answer (score 0):

You can customise Bootstrap styles by overriding them with your own CSS.

See the Customizing section on the Bootstrap website for information on how it's done:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#customizing

Comment: I think it's actually max-width that you're after. Try #narrowon2 { max-width: 60px; }

Comment: It is possible to edit maxlength with css @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SLA, new {style="@maxlength = "3"} )